"Git commit error: Title cannot contain 'git commit error'"
PS C:\GitHubRePo\noting> git commit -m 'dsddssd'
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'HelloWorld0328/main'.`

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   FrontEnd/noting (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I tried committing several times and deleted the repository several times. But it's still like this, please help me
PS C:\GitHubRePo\noting> git commit -m 'dsddssd'
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'HelloWorld0328/main'.`

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   FrontEnd/noting (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I tried committing several times and deleted the repository several times. But it's still like this, please help me.

What's the output from git show HEAD? Does it match what you were expecting that commit to change?

Im a little bit confused by your question but I think you might be having a problem with a submodule in your git repo. If you’ve made changes within a submodule you have to first add and then commit those changes. From the root repo:
Cd path/to/submodule
git add .
git commit -m "Update submodule changes"

Then go back into the main repo and add and commit the changes which will update the is submodule head that is being referenced to.
Cd ../..
git add .
git commit -m "Update submodule reference"

Then you can push your changes.
